# Series expansions

Tags: series-expansion

I am not a very experienced user. My problem is that I have a polynomial equation

F[Z,a,b,c]=0

in which parameters a, b and c are series of another variable x. What I look for is how to generate the coefficients of the series for Z as functions of x. I used brutal force but it is just a nightmare.

Thank for your help

Comment: Could you post a possibly smaller version of your functions explicitly ?

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Here we go. The equation is Y^3-(1-c1)Y^2+(A-c1+c2)Y-c2=0 where c1=k1 x,c2=k2 x^2 and A-k3 x (1+k4 Log[x]). The development is for x=1

Comment: Try using `Reduce` to solve for `y`, then make the substitutions for `c1, c2, A` and finally use `Series`  for the expansion.

Comment: Could you be more explicit for the stupid idiot I am ? I never been able to use Reduce for anything. Could you give an example for this practical problem ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Claude, don't forget to use @ + name in comment replies. If you don't do that, the addressee won't be notified.

Comment: Try `sol1 = Reduce[y^3 - (1 - c1) y^2 + (A - c1 + c2) y - c2 == 0, y][[1, 
    2]] // ToRadicals`. `sol` is the first (of three) solutions to your equation.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to solve `F[Z,a,b,c]=0` with `a,b,c` as functions of `x` and then you can expand it as series. The general structure will be like

```
sol = Z /. Solve[F[Z,a[x],b[x],c[x] == 0, Z];
```

and then

```
Table[Coefficient[Z, x , i],{i,1,n}] (*n = max power*)
```

Let me show you an example.

```
a[x_] := Sin[x]; b[x_] := Cos[x]; c[x_] := Exp[x];
F[Z, a, b, c] = Z^2 + a[x] + b[x] + c[x];
sol = Z /. Solve[F[Z, a, b, c] == 0, Z];
```

Since I use $Z^2$, there will be two solutions. You can use `Coefficient` on each of them, but if the resulting function is too complicated (as in this case $\pm \sqrt{Sin[x]+Cos[x]+e^x}$ ), it may fail to return anything. To be in safe side use `Series` expansion first.

```
x0 = 0; n = 5; (*for expansion around x0 to power n*)
sol2 = Series[sol, {x, x0, n}];
coeff=Table[Coefficient[sol2, x, i], {i, 1, n}];
```

And `coeff` is what you are looking for. Since there are two solutions for `Z`, `coeff` will be a two column data set, first column for the coefficients of the first solution and second one for second (just check `TableForm[coeff]`).

Now if you want to use the polynomial to power `n`, just use

```
poly=Normal[sol2];
```

`poly[[1]]` and `poly[[2]]` are what you want.